# Create a structured NSDictionary from a NSArray

Tags: ios, loops, nsarray, nsdictionary, key-value

I need to create a structured `NSDictionary` with grouped keys, starting from a `NSArray`.
This is an example:

```
[
    {
        section = section1,
        category = category1,
        date = 2011-12-01,
        key1 = foo,
        key2 = bar
    },
    {
        section = section1,
        category = category2,
        date = 2011-12-01,
        key1 = foo,
        key2 = bar
    },
    {
        section = section1,
        category = category2,
        date = 2011-12-03
        key1 = foo,
        key2 = bar
    },
    {
        section = section2,
        category = category1,
        date = 2011-12-03
        key1 = foo,
        key2 = bar
    }
]
```

The result should be a `NSDictionary` like this (I didn't checked that the values are ok, I just want to give the idea):

```
[
    section1 = {
        category1 = {
            2011-12-01 = 
                [{
                    key1 = foo;
                    key2 = bar;
                },
                {
                    key1 = foo;
                    key2 = bar;
                }
                ]
            }
        },
        category2 = {
            2011-12-01 =
                [{
                    key1 = foo;
                    key2 = bar;
                }],
        }
    },
    section2 = {
        category1 = {
            2011-12-01 =
                [{
                    key1 = foo;
                    key2 = bar;
                }]
        }
    }
]
```

Can I achieve this using `NSPredicate` or Key-Value Coding, and avoid many loops?

**My proposed solution**

```
NSMutableDictionary *sectionEmpty = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *values = [records allValues];

NSArray *sections = [[records allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.section"];

for(NSString *section in sections) {
    // Find records for section
    NSArray *sectionRecords = [values filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"section == %@",section]];

    // Find unique categories
    NSArray *categorys = [sectionRecords valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.category"];

    // Loop through categories
    for (NSString *category in categorys) {

        // Creating temporary record
        NSMutableDictionary *empty = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        // Find records for category
        NSArray *categoryRecords = [sectionRecords filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == %@",category]];

        // Find unique dates
        NSArray *dates = [categoryRecords valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.date"];

        // Loop through dates
        for (NSString *date in dates) {

            // Creating temporary record
            NSMutableDictionary *emptyDate = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

            // Find records for dates
            NSArray *dateRecords = [categoryRecords filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@",date]];

            // Split date
            NSString *dateString = [[date componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];

            // Check if date exist in temporary record
            if(![[emptyDate allKeys] containsObject:dateString]){
                [emptyDate setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:dateString];
            }

            // Set date records for date key
            [[emptyDate objectForKey:dateString] addObject:dateRecords];

            // Set date for category
            [empty setObject:emptyDate forKey:category];
        }

        // Set category for section
        [sectionEmpty setObject:empty forKey:section];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way you can achieve what you want is a series of nested for loops (for each level: section, category, date). In the innermost loop you create a complex predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"section = %@ AND category = %@ AND date = %@",
                          section, category, date];
```

Then you filter out the input array, and construct new array of dictionaries with `key1` and `key2` only. You add this dates array to categories dictionary for a given date, and then you add a categories dictionary to the output dictionary for a given category. I don't see any simpler way of doing this.

```
NSArray *input = [records allValues];
NSMutableDictionary *output = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


NSArray *sections = [NSArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.section"];
NSArray *categories = [NSArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.category"];
NSArray *dates = [NSArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.date"];

NSPredicate *predicate;
for (NSString *section in sections) {
    NSMutableDictionary *categoriesDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for (NSString *category in categories) {
        NSMutableArray *datesArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (NSString *date in dates) {
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                         @"section = %@ AND category = %@ AND date = %@",
                         section, category, date];

            NSArray *filteredInput = [input filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
            if (filteredInput.count > 0) {
                NSMutableArray *filteredOutput = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:filteredInput.count];

                [filteredInput enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                    [filteredOutput addObject:
                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [obj objectForKey:@"key1"], @"key1",
                      [obj objectForKey:@"key2"], @"key2", nil]
                     ];
                }];

                if (filteredOutput.count > 0)
                    [datesArray addObject:filteredOutput];
            }
        }
        if (datesArray.count > 0)
            [categoriesDictionary setObject:datesArray forKey:category];
    }
    if (categoriesDictionary.count > 0)
        [output setObject:categoriesDictionary forKey:section];
}
```

Comment: I've added the solution I've just created. Please let me know if you have a better one.

Comment: I updated my answer, though the general idea is the same and there's nothing revolutionary. I'm filtering the array only once but I'm not sure if it would get any faster than your implementation.